# How to group field data?

Tags: mysql

I have sql query to show data

```
"SELECT
  `artikel`.`foto_naam`,
  `fotografer`.`id`,
  `fotografer`.`name_fotografer`,
  `customer`.`first_name`,
  `customer`.`last_name`,
  `fotografer`.`domain_name`,
  `fotografer`.`email`,
  `order`.`invoice_no`,
  `order`.`order_cost`,
  `order`.`total_cost`,
  `order`.`invoice_date`,
  `order`.`payment`,
  `order`.`status`
FROM
  `artikel_group`
  INNER JOIN `artikel` ON `artikel`.`artikelgroup_id` = `artikel_group`.`id`
  INNER JOIN `fotografer` ON `artikel_group`.`fotografer_id` = `fotografer`.`id`
  INNER JOIN `order_has_artikelgroup` ON `order_has_artikelgroup`.`artikelgroup_id` = `artikel_group`.`id`
  INNER JOIN `order` ON `order`.`id` = `order_has_artikelgroup`.`order_id` 
  INNER JOIN `customer` ON `order`.`customer_id` = `customer`.`id`"
```

The query result for my sql query in btowser i use php framework codeigniter

```
Name  | email           | customer | invoice id| 
Lekto | lekto@gmail.com | edwin    | 11        |
Lekto | lekto@gmail.com | risa     | 12        |
Lekto | lekto@gmail.com | edwin    | 13        |
heko  | heko@gmail.com  | pae      | 15        |
heko  | heko@gmail.com  | edwin    | 16        |
```

How to group field like

```
Name  | email           | customer | invoice id|
Lekto | lekto@gmail.com | edwin    | 11        |
      |                 | risa     | 12        |
      |                 | edwin    | 13        |
heko  | heko@gmail.com  | pae      | 15        |
      |                 | edwin    | 16        |
```

please help to show the query like this

Comment: do it on the application level `:)` mysql doesn't supports window functions (*which could make your desired result easy*)

Answer (score 1):

Odd question, but if you REALLY NEED THIS in MySQL then you could use USER VARIABLES to set the `Name` and `email` column to '' (empty string) for subitems in the list.

**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7bc47/6)** or e.g.

```
select 
    if(@tName!= Name, if(@'tNAME':= Name, Name,Name) , '' ),
    if(@tEmail!= Email, if(@'tEmail':= Email, Email ,Email) , '' ),
    customer,
    invoice_id,
    /* blah blah blah */
from 
    tables
    join (select @'tName':='', @'tEmail':='') T on 1=1 
/* blah blah blah */
```

I provide the `join (select @'tName':='') T on 1=1` to re-initialize the user variable just in case you can't control them.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do in mysql is to wrap you query with a `group by` and `group_concat()`. Something like this:

```
SELECT
    name, 
    email, 
    group_concat(customer) AS customers, 
    group_concat(invoice_id) AS invoice_ids
FROM
    (...query you already have..)
GROUP BY
    name, email
```

Result will look like something like this:

```
name    email               customers           invoice_ids

heko    heko@gmail.com      pae,edwin           15,16
Lekto   lekto@gmail.com     edwin,risa,edwin    11,12,13
```

[PLZ SEE FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d5458/2/0)

Comment: result query pae,edwin with comas how to make <br/>? making list?

Comment: @EdwinAndrianto i'm not familiar with php but i'm sure you can replace the comma's with `<br/>` in php side. A very bad but working alternative is to set the separator of group_concat to `<br/>`: `group_concat(invoice_id separator '<br/>')`